# Window width in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, size, width

I have some mystic troubles with `$(window).width()`.

I open my site in Chrome Device Toolbar with `320xXXX` window size. Then, I run in Google Chrome JavaScript console `$(window).width()` and it says `980`. And that's why none of my `@media` in css not working. Is there is any explanation for that?

By the way, when I resize Chrome window, it magicaly start to see correct window width.

Comment: Did you add the viewport tag `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`?

Comment: @ĐàoMinhHạt, wow, you are right! Thanks for response! Add this as answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As OP's comment, here is the answer.

You will need to add `viewport` tag to archive `@media` css

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```